# Accessing form from directive

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to access the current form (which may be nested) from within an angularjs directive. I know I can use

> require: 'form'

or

> require: '^form'

to go up a level but what if the directive I'm designing can live 1 level deep on one form and three levels deep on another?

> require: '^form' or require: '^^^form' etc

How can I design my directive to require the nearest form to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how far down the directive is nested. It will search up until it finds an ancestor with that controller, or it will throw an error.

So if you have a directive like this:

```
    app.directive("formSpice", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "^form",
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.formName = ctrl.$name;
            }
        };
    });
```

And a your markup looks like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="well" form-spice>
        <h3>Level 1 - Form Name: {{formName}}</h3>
        <div class="well" form-spice>
            <h3>Level 2 - Form Name: {{formName}}</h3>
            <div class="well" form-spice>
                <h3>Level 3 - Form Name: {{formName}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It will still find the form in all three instances.

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/FtMjt/)